# Releasing C++ resources and fork-exec?

Tags: c++, linux, singleton, exec

I'm trying to spawn a new process from my C++-project using fork-exec. I'm using fork-exec in order to create a bi-directional pipe to the child process. But I'm afraid my resources in the forked process won't get freed properly, since the exec-call will completely take over my process and is not going to call any destructors.

I tried circumventing this by throwing an exception and calling execl from a catch block at the end of main, but this solution doesn't destruct any singletons.

Is there any sensible way to achieve this safely? (hopefully avoiding any atExit hacks)

Ex: The following code outputs:

```
We are the child, gogo!
Parent proc, do nothing
Destroying object
```

Even though the forked process also has a copy of the singleton which needs to be destructed before I call execl.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class Resources
{
public:
    ~Resources() { cout<<"Destroying object\n"; }
};

Resources& getRes()
{
    static Resources r1;
    return r1;
}

void makeChild(const string &command)
{
    int pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
    case -1:
        cout<<"Big error! Wtf!\n";
        return;
    case 0:
        cout<<"Parent proc, do nothing\n";
        return;
    }
    cout<<"We are the child, gogo!\n";
    throw command;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        Resources& ref = getRes();
        makeChild("child");
    }
    catch(const string &command)
    {
        execl(command.c_str(), "");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which resources are you talking about? Mostly file descriptors survive exec(), which you can mark close-on-exec so that the kernel closes them for you. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html

Comment: By the way, if destructors were called in the forked child as well as in the parent, it would end up calling constructors once (in the parent) and destructors twice (both in the parent and the child).

Comment: I believe I'm getting dangerously close to undefined behaviour here, but the Resources class represents several singleton classes I use for wrapping C-libraries into RAII-objects. And if fork really copies the entire process state, then I should probably call the RAII-destructors before I call exec(). This would of course be insane if the resources were external to the program(like a database connection). But since they're libraries I believe they should be released in both the parent and the child process. [If it helps, I'm currently wrapping ncurses, nscapi and SDL into singletons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are excellent odds that you don't *need* to call any destructors in between `fork` and `exec`.  Yeah, `fork` makes a copy of your entire process state, including objects that have destructors, and `exec` obliterates all that state.  But does it actually matter?  Can an observer from outside your program -- another, unrelated process running on the same computer -- tell that destructors weren't run in the child?  If there's no way to tell, there's no need to run them.

Even if an external observer can tell, it may be *actively wrong* to run destructors in the child.  The usual example for this is: imagine you wrote something to `stdout` before calling `fork`, but it got buffered in the library and so has not actually been delivered to the operating system yet.  In that case, you *must not* call `fclose` or `fflush` on `stdout` in the child, or the output will happen twice!  (This is also why you almost certainly should call `_exit` instead of `exit` if the `exec` fails.)

Having said all that, there are two common cases where you might need to do some cleanup work in the child.  One is file descriptors (*do not* confuse these with stdio FILEs or iostream objects) that should not be open after the `exec`.  The correct way to deal with these is to set the [`FD_CLOEXEC`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) flag on them as soon as possible after they are *opened* (some OSes allow you to do this in `open` itself, but that's not universal) and/or to loop from 3 to some large number calling `close` (*not* `fclose`) in the child.  (FreeBSD has [`closefrom`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=closefrom), but as far as I know, nobody else does, which is a shame because it's really quite handy.)

The other case is system-global thread locks, which - this is a thorny and poorly standardized area - *may* wind up held by both the parent and the child, and then inherited across `exec` into a process that has no idea it holds a lock.  This is what [`pthread_atfork`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/pthread_atfork.3.asp) is supposed to be for, but I have read that in practice it doesn't work reliably.  The only advice I can offer is "don't be holding any locks when you call `fork`", say sorry.

Comment: Thanks! This hammered out all the misunderstandings I had. (...Especially so because it allows me to ignore unreleased resources in the child process with a good conscience =)

Comment: Good explanation; under Linux it is possible to emulate closefrom(), but in any case, it is a very ugly hack and I wouldn't recommend it.